# Javascript numbers representing limits of inequality comparisons

Tags: javascript, numbers, inequality

I am working with a set of values such that 0 < value < 1.  I want to validate some data such that a value outside this range is modified to the closest valid value.  After some experimentation, I discovered `Number.MIN_VALUE` as the best way of representing the lower limit.  However, the upper limit, `1 - Number.MIN_VALUE`, has unexpected behaviour:

Whereas:

`Number.MIN_VALUE; //5e-324` and `Number.MIN_VALUE > 0; //true`

`1 - Number.MIN_VALUE; //1` and `1 - Number.MIN_VALUE < 1; //false`

So, what is the best way of generating the smallest and largest numbers in Javascript that satisfy an inequality of the form a < value < b?

Comment: What about `Number.MAX_VALUE` ?

Comment: in my mind Number.MIN_VALUE is a dummy value, which allows only to test, not to participate in operations

Comment: The problem is that numbers don't have enough precision to represent `1 - Number.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: @Barmar - I figured as much.  But I'm looking to get the first representable value above or below a given value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mantissa of a JavaScript float has 52 bits. With denormalization, the minimum float can be extremely small, `5e-324` -- this is represented as something like 51 zero bits, 1 one bit, and the most negative exponent.

But you can't get that close to `1`, because the representation of this will be all one bits, and you can't increase the range using exponents. It's limited by the floating point precision.

So the value will be as given below:

```js
console.log(1 - .5**53);
```

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry for the delayed response - moved on to other things.  But can now go back and implement this, thanks!

Comment: Yesterday I got a response from a 2-year-old answer :)